# How to sort a column in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have query:

```
select distinct ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createdate, 113)) 
from CRM 
for xml path('');
```

It runs fine and give me this string:

```
,[22 Jul 2013],[28 Jul 2013],[03 Aug 2013],[13 Aug 2013],[30 Jul 2013],[23 Jul 2013],[31 Jul 2013],[19 Jul 2013],[05 Aug 2013],[12 Aug 2013],[26 Jul 2013],[18 Jul 2013],[09 Aug 2013],[20 Jul 2013],[25 Jul 2013],[08 Aug 2013],[11 Aug 2013],[07 Aug 2013],[29 Jul 2013],[06 Aug 2013],[02 Aug 2013],[24 Jul 2013],[17 Jul 2013],[14 Aug 2013],[01 Aug 2013],[21 Jul 2013],[10 Aug 2013],[04 Aug 2013],[27 Jul 2013],[16 Jul 2013]
```

The problem is that it is not sorting the column as a `Date` but as a string. I tried sorting the column inside the inner query:

```
select distinct ',' + quotename(dt) 
from 
   (select  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createDate, 113) as dt 
    from crm 
    order by dt asc)  
for xml path('');
```

but no success, it says:

> Error 1033: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Somebody please help me how to sort out this problem? Thanks a lot in advance, I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if you use `group by` instead of `distinct` :

```
select ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createDate, 113))
from crm 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createDate, 113)
order by CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createDate, 113), 113)
for xml path('');
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify `top 100 percent` in the subquery to allow ordering:

```
(select top 100 percent
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createDate, 113) as dt 
    from crm 
    order by dt asc)
```

Alternatively, you can omit the subquery entirely.  The `distinct` requires that you sort on the exact column you select:

```
select distinct ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createdate, 113)) 
from CRM 
order by ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createdate, 113)) 
for xml path('');
```

EDIT: In reply to your comment, you can order on `createDate` instead of `dt`:

```
select  distinct ',' + quotename(dt) 
from    (
        select  top 100 percent CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), createDate, 113) as dt
        from    crm 
        order by 
                createDate
        )  
for xml path('')
```

Because of the `distinct`, this only works with a subquery.

Comment: tried it but still sorting in string way, sorts from 01 Aug... to 01 Jul (string way).

Comment: using "group by" solved my issue, thanks a lot for your help though.